# uploading image Asp.net core 3.1 with postgresql

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to upload a image in asp .NET core. I could not upload the image.
There is no error message. all are work correctly without uploading the image.
anyone tell me what is problem in these codes
also I have a folder "Uploads" in the wwwroot folder.
I attach my codes below.

This is my Create.cshtml

```
@model  WebApplication1.ViewModels.EmployeeViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Employee</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create" enctype="multipart/form-data ">

            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="EmployeeName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="EmployeeName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="EmployeeName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="EmployeeProfile" class="control-label"></label>
                <div class="custom-file">
                    <input type="file" asp-for="EmployeeProfile" class="custom-file-input" />
                    <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
                </div>
                <span asp-validation-for="EmployeeProfile" class="text-danger"></span>

                @*<label asp-for="EmployeeImage" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="EmployeeImage" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="EmployeeImage" class="text-danger"></span>*@
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DepartmentId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="DepartmentId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.DepartmentId"></select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary rounded-0" />
                <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary rounded-0">Back to List</a>

                @*<a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>*@
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


@section Scripts {
    <script>
        // Add the following code if you want the name of the file appear on select
        $(".custom-file-input").on("change", function () {
            var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
            $(this).siblings(".custom-file-label").addClass("selected").html(fileName);
        });
    </script>
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

this is my EmployeesController

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApplication1.Models;
using WebApplication1.ViewModels;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly EmployeeDbContext _context;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment;

        public EmployeesController(EmployeeDbContext context, IWebHostEnvironment hostEnvironment)
        {
            _context = context;
            webHostEnvironment = hostEnvironment;
        }

        // GET: Employees
        //public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        //{
        //    var employeeDbContext = _context.Employees.Include(e => e.Department);
        //    return View(await employeeDbContext.ToListAsync());
        //}

        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? pageNumber)
        {
            ViewData["CurrentSort"] = sortOrder;
            ViewData["NameSortParm"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";

            if (searchString != null)
            {
                pageNumber = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }
            //var employeeDbContext = _context.Employees.Include(e => e.Department);
            
            ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;
            var employee = from em in _context.Employees.Include(e => e.Department)
             select em;
            // var employee = from e in _context.Employees

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                employee = employee.Where(em => em.EmployeeName.Contains(searchString)
                                       || em.EmployeeName.Contains(searchString));
            }

            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "name_desc":
                    employee = employee.OrderByDescending(em => em.EmployeeName);
                    break;

                default:
                    employee = employee.OrderBy(em => em.EmployeeName);
                    break;
            }

            int pageSize = 3;
            return View(await PaginatedList<Employee>.CreateAsync(employee.AsNoTracking(), pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize));

            //return View(await _context.Departments.ToListAsync());
        }


        // GET: Employees/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var employee = await _context.Employees
                .Include(e => e.Department)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

            var EmployeeViewModel = new EmployeeViewModel()
            {
                Id = employee.Id,
                EmployeeName = employee.EmployeeName,
                DepartmentId = employee.DepartmentId,
                ExistingImage = employee.EmployeeImage
            };

            if (employee == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(employee);
        }

        // GET: Employees/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewData["DepartmentId"] = new SelectList(_context.Departments, "Id", "departmentName");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Employees/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("EmployeeName,EmployeeImage,DepartmentId")] EmployeeViewModel model)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                string uniqueFileName = ProcessUploadedFile(model);
                Employee employee = new Employee
                {
                    EmployeeName = model.EmployeeName,
                    DepartmentId = model.DepartmentId,
                    EmployeeImage = uniqueFileName
                };

                _context.Add(employee);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            ViewData["DepartmentId"] = new SelectList(_context.Departments, "Id", "departmentName", model.DepartmentId);
            return View(model);
        }

        // GET: Employees/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var employee = await _context.Employees.FindAsync(id);

            var EmployeeViewModel = new EmployeeViewModel()
            {
                Id = employee.Id,
                EmployeeName = employee.EmployeeName,
                DepartmentId = employee.DepartmentId,
                ExistingImage = employee.EmployeeImage
            }; if (employee == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            ViewData["DepartmentId"] = new SelectList(_context.Departments, "Id", "departmentName", employee.DepartmentId);
            return View(EmployeeViewModel);
        }

        // POST: Employees/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,EmployeeName,EmployeeImage,DepartmentId")] EmployeeViewModel model)
        {
            if (id != model.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var employee = await _context.Employees.FindAsync(model.Id);
                employee.EmployeeName = model.EmployeeName;
                employee.DepartmentId = model.DepartmentId;

                if (model.EmployeeProfile != null)
                {
                    if (model.ExistingImage != null)
                    {
                        string filePath = Path.Combine(webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Uploads", model.ExistingImage);
                        System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
                    }

                    employee.EmployeeImage = ProcessUploadedFile(model);
                }
                _context.Update(employee);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                //try
                //{
                //    _context.Update(model);
                //    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                //}
                //catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                //{
                //    if (!EmployeeExists(model.Id))
                //    {
                //        return NotFound();
                //    }
                //    else
                //    {
                //        throw;
                //    }
                //}
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            ViewData["DepartmentId"] = new SelectList(_context.Departments, "Id", "departmentName", model.DepartmentId);
            return View();
        }

        // GET: Employees/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var employee = await _context.Employees
                .Include(e => e.Department)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

            var EmployeeViewModel = new EmployeeViewModel()
            {
                Id = employee.Id,
                EmployeeName = employee.EmployeeName,
                DepartmentId = employee.DepartmentId,
                ExistingImage = employee.EmployeeImage
            };


            if (employee == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(EmployeeViewModel);
        }

        // POST: Employees/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var employee = await _context.Employees.FindAsync(id);
            var CurrentImage = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot\\Uploads", employee.EmployeeImage);
            _context.Employees.Remove(employee);

            if (await _context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0)
            {
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(CurrentImage))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(CurrentImage);
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool EmployeeExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Employees.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }

        private string ProcessUploadedFile(EmployeeViewModel model)
        {
            string uniqueFileName = null;
            

            if (model.EmployeeProfile != null)
            {
                string uploadsFolder = Path.Combine(webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Uploads");
           //     uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + model.EmployeeProfile.FileName;
                uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + Path.GetFileName(model.EmployeeProfile.FileName);
                string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, uniqueFileName);
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    model.EmployeeProfile.CopyTo(fileStream);
                }


            }

            return uniqueFileName;
        }
    }
}
```

This is ProcessUploadedFile method

```
 private string ProcessUploadedFile(EmployeeViewModel model)
        {
            string uniqueFileName = null;
            

            if (model.EmployeeProfile != null)
            {
                string uploadsFolder = Path.Combine(webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Uploads");
           //     uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + model.EmployeeProfile.FileName;
                uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + Path.GetFileName(model.EmployeeProfile.FileName);
                string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, uniqueFileName);
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    model.EmployeeProfile.CopyTo(fileStream);
                }


            }

            return uniqueFileName;
        }
```

i have 3 viewmodels,  see below
EmployeeViewModel
EditImageViewModel
UploadImageViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebApplication1.Models;
using WebApplication1.ViewModels;

namespace WebApplication1.ViewModels
{

    public class EmployeeViewModel : EditImageViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Employee Name")]
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }


        // Navigation Properties
        public int? DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public Department Department { get; set; }

    }
}



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication1.ViewModels
{
    public class EditImageViewModel : UploadImageViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ExistingImage { get; set; }

    }
}

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication1.ViewModels
{
    public class UploadImageViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please choose profile image")]
        [Display(Name = "Profile Picture")]
        public IFormFile EmployeeProfile { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have commented out the EmployeeImage, you only passed the EmployeeProfile to action, but

you didn't **bind the EmployeeProfile**.

Change to this:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("EmployeeName,EmployeeProfile,//***others")] EmployeeViewModel model)
```

Then I can upload the file using your code.

The **[Bind]** **specifies which properties of a model** should be included in model binding.Check:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#bind-attribute

whole code:

```
        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("EmployeeName,EmployeeProfile")] EmployeeViewModel model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            string uniqueFileName = ProcessUploadedFile(model);
            Employee employee = new Employee
            {
                EmployeeName = model.EmployeeName,
                EmployeeImage = uniqueFileName
            };
            _context.Add(employee);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
   

    private string ProcessUploadedFile(EmployeeViewModel model)
    {
        string uniqueFileName = null;

        if (model.EmployeeProfile != null)
        {
            string uploadsFolder = Path.Combine(webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Uploads");
            //     uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + model.EmployeeProfile.FileName;
            uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + Path.GetFileName(model.EmployeeProfile.FileName);
            string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, uniqueFileName);
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                model.EmployeeProfile.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
        }
        return uniqueFileName;
    }
```

Create.cshtml:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Create" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="EmployeeName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="EmployeeName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="EmployeeName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="EmployeeProfile" class="control-label"></label>
            <div class="custom-file">
                <input type="file" asp-for="EmployeeProfile" class="custom-file-input" />
                <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
            </div>
            <span asp-validation-for="EmployeeProfile" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary rounded-0" />
            <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary rounded-0">Back to List</a>

        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Model:

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeImage { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }    
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public IFormFile EmployeeProfile { get; set; }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: but still, image is not uploading

Comment: @hanushi I have edit my post with whole code,you can set a breakpoint to your actions to check  whether the properties have been posted correctly

Comment: i have 3 viewmodels,  see above, i have edited now
EmployeeViewModel 
EditImageViewModel
UploadImageViewModel, my IFormFile is in the UplodeImageVIewModel.. now what should i do??

Comment: @hanushi I can upload the image after using your three models. Have you set a break point to check the properties? In your newest code, you still didn't bind the employeeprofile to create action, so the Create action will not be able to get it's value.

Comment: i changed bind the employeeprofile in my code.  sorry i didnt update above

Comment: i set break point and check.it shows EmployeeProfile as null it does not seems like yours one

Comment: in my code my IFormFile is in the UplodeImageVIewModel,